# An array that will declare 5 random numbers from 0 to 100. Then it will average all the numbers that are over 70

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, average

This is the homework question that I need to answer.

Write a complete program that declares an array of any five integers, from 0 to 100 , and   averages only those integers which are greater than 70 .

Here is my code I have written so far.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class TestLoop{ 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random Rnum = new Random();
        int[] ar1 = new int[100];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ar1[i] = Rnum.nextInt(100);
               System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");

        if(ar1[i] > 70)    

            System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to get my five random numbers, but I can't seem to figure out how to average the ones that will be over 70. The last few lines of code are my attempt to isolate the numebrs that are over 70 from the others are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random Rnum = new Random();
    int[] ar1 = new int[100];
    int counter=0;
    double total=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ar1[i] = Rnum.nextInt(100);
           System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");

        if(ar1[i] > 70)
        {    
            total+=ar1[i];
            counter++;
            System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");
        }
    }
    if(counter>0)
    {
        double average=total/counter;
        System.out.println("average="+average);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, That works. I did have to delete the System.out.print right after the counter ++ though. It was making it look like the program had more than 5 numbers. So, what I needed needed to make a total and counter variable, so that I can divide the counter from the total. I'm looking over this and I think i understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply keep track of how many numbers there are above 70 and what the sum of them is.
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random Rnum = new Random();

```
//added variables
int count = 0;
int average = 0;

int[] ar1 = new int[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ar1[i] = Rnum.nextInt(100);
       System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");

if(ar1[i] > 70)    
    // increment count
    count++;
    // add the number greater than 70 to the average
    average += ar[i];
    System.out.print(ar1[i] + "  ");
}

//once out of the loop devide the sum of all     //integers greater than 70 (stored in average) by //the number of integers that were greater than 70 (stored in count)
```

average = average / count;

System.out.println(average);
}

Comment: Thnak you also. I apreciate you taking the time to answer.